# Why does fluorescence emission detector pick up second order wavelengths with first order scan, even though they have different angles?

Tags: interference, spectroscopy, diffraction, photon-emission, fluorescence

my question in more detail and with an example: Let's say I have a 980nm laser and I use that laser to excite my fluorescent solution in cuvette. My scan range is from 300 to 800nm. If, for example I want to detect emission at 490nm, and I don't use any filters, I get a second order diffraction from laser scatter.

I know that when 980nm laser light hits difraction grating in monochromator, I have the first order 980nm, and second order 490nm diffraction which overlap at the same angle. For this example purposes let's say I have an angle of 29 degrees. But if I scan my emission for 490nm, the first diffraction angle of that wavelength is 14 degrees.

So why isn't it possible to adjust the angle, (of diffraction grating or any mirrors) so only the first diffraction of 490nm light goes out?

*I do understand that 980nm first order light angle is the same as 490nm second order angle, but why can't just the first order 490nm angle be recorded?*

Or maybe the detector combines all orders of the same wavelength? If so, how?

**EDIT: THIS MUST BE IT.** The diffraction is grating is turned to such angle that the 490nm light from all of the orders can be seen trough emission slit, that would explain how 980nm laser scattering reaches the detector (trough second order diffraction of 490nm). But even then, isn't it possible to not alow other diffraction orders to not pass, so we don't have to use filters, etc ? 
**EDIT2:** But then again if diffraction grating is on such angle that it receives both first and second diffraction of 490nm, doesns't that just mean it basically covers all spectrum? (Angle between first order 490nm and 980nm)

***Does not make any sense***, anyone ?

https://terpconnect.umd.edu/~toh/models/matlab/whitegratingBBLarge.png 
This is an image to help me illustrate the problem. As you can see if I scan for 400nm light, the only second order diffraction I can encounter is 200nm. How does my 800nm (just an example) laser scatter can interfere with that? It's in completely different place. I get a scatter peak when scanning 400nm emission from laser. (Or 490nm emission scan and 980nm laser, just using 400nm for illustrative purposes)

Regards,
L.K.

Comment: That's how it is, especially since the laser intensity is much stronger then fluorescence (it seems that you need multiphoton excitation). Find an optical filter that blocks infrared light and put it in front of your spectrometer, this will solve your problem.

Comment: The problem is.. I know how to eliminate it, but it's not clear to me why in an 300-800nm scan, I get a laser scatter peak at 490nm. At that angle I should get either 490nm emission light, or second diffraction 245nm light. Why do I see a 980nm laser scatter at that angle ?

Comment: Yes, I was mistaken because the second-order peak would come from 245 nm. Another possible explanation is frequency doubling in an anisotropic medium, for instance, in a wall of quartz cuvette. Do you use quartz cuvettes? Maybe you could find a plastic one to see if the effect disappears.

Comment: No, I've used basic standard plastic cuvette.

Comment: Theoretically, there should not be this half-order scattering. One option is, as mentioned, second harmonic generation somewhere along the laser path, but you would then probably see some turquoise light by eye. Second option is imperfection of your monochromator. I'm not a big specialist in those, but I've read that "in some grating instruments scattered or redispersed light from the zero order or doubly dispersed light from other orders [leads] to the observation of pseudo-half-order spectra".

Comment: https://books.google.ch/books?id=Lbe3iBfKc_IC&lpg=PA110&ots=5CzNnA8M20&dq=diffraction%20grating%20%22half%20order%22&pg=PA110#v=onepage&q=diffraction%20grating%20%22half%20order%22&f=false